# Drupal daylight savings issue

Tags: 7

My drupal installation is still displaying summer time after the daylight savings switch yesterday. Wrong dates include the following pages:

- Views displaying nodes with created/updated fields
- Drupal reports
  page

My timezone is set in drupal config to Europe/Bratislava. I have tested the raw `date()` function in the web server, and it returns the correct time.

It seems that dates are saved correctly by timestamp using a `time()` function; the problem is displaying. Can anybody tell what is wrong? Is it a bug, or something else?

---

I have already found a problem. Drupal variable `date_default_timezone` was set to 7200 for Europe/Bratislava timezone. In fact, the correct value for winter time is 3600 for this timezone.

Solution was to resave the timezone settings under the Drupal "Date and time" configuration within the administration menu. It will then adjust the `date_default_timezone` variable.

I am just curious, why is this switch not happening automatically?

Comment: Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Comment: In the U.S., daylight savings time does not change until 4 November. http://www.time.gov/timezone.cgi?Pacific/d/-8/java  Perhaps there is some bug related to time/date handling, although it is surprising that Drupal is not simply using the system time. It would probably be best to address this in the issue queue on Drupal.org.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Daylight saving time](http://drupal.org/project/dst) module.

> This module intended to work with Daylight saving time. It replaces
>   system time offset and has preferences for each user and full site.
>
> Used to display correct time of creation of documents etc.